# Get selected value text from dropdown with XML AND PHP

Tags: php, html, xml

I have the next code:

```
<form method="POST">
<?php
 echo "<select value>";
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss",null,true);
   foreach($xml->channel->item as $news)
{
   echo "<option value='".$news->title."'>" . $news->title . "</option>";
   }
   echo "</select>";
 ?>
</form>
```

So i have a dropdown box with news titles, when i select a title i want to appear the description from the xml file and i dont know how to do it, if someone can help me, please

Comment: You would be better doing something with xpath to find the corresponding story - something like `//item[title="optionSelected"]`

Comment: In my opinion You have to use jquery. eg. jQuery.parseXML()

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example and let me know if you want any more help.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".feeds").change(function(){
        var val=$(this).val();
            $(".common").hide();
            $("."+val).show();
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
    .common{display:none;}
</style>

<?php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss",null,true);
$select_html="<select class='feeds'>";
$d_html="";

foreach($xml->channel->item as $news){
    $d_html.="<div class='".$news->guid." common'>".$news->description.'</div>';
    $select_html.="<option value='".$news->guid."'>" . $news->title . "</option>";
}
$select_html.="</select>";

echo $select_html;
echo $d_html;
?>
```